How do I configure a Many to Many relationship where one side has 2 collections in ef core
So as the title said, I have the following entities:
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Group> SourceGroups { get; set; }
    public List<Group> DestinationGroups { get; set; }
}

and I want to establish a many to many relationship between them.
the problem lies in the fact I have 2 collections in the Link entity, so ef core has to know about if it is source or destination.
I tried to add a value that determines if the group is source or destination to a custom join entity:
public class LinkGroup
{
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSource { get; set; }
}

But I couldn't find a way to configure ef core to automatically use the IsSource value and populate the right values into the right collection.
I also tried to create 2 different join entities and configure each one separately:
public class LinkDestinationGroup
{
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class LinkSourceGroup
{
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

using the an OnModelCreating that looks roughly like so:
public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Link>().HasMany(e => e.SourceGroups).WithMany(e => e.Links).UsingEntity<LinkSourceGroup>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Link>().HasMany(e => e.DestinationGroups).WithMany(e => e.Links).UsingEntity<LinkDestinationGroup>();
}

yet I encountered an error on ef core side.

You can do what YBB said or simply add a GroupType table with two records, Source and Destination. Then you can put one collection inside Link public List Groups. Just use the GroupTypeId to differentiate in code.

Yes adding a lookup table would be better for normalization in this case.

When Collections are "optional", I've resorted to "dictionaries of collections". Then I have a "Has( id )" method that I can use before attempting to access any "optional" collections; or just return an empty collection. I include "empty" collections (references) among the "optional"; it is just overhead if you have many objects.

Using two seperate tables for this case can solve the problem:
Group :
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkDestinationGroup> DestinationGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkSourceGroup> SourceGroups { get; set; }
}

Link :
public class Link
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkDestinationGroup> DestinationGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkSourceGroup> SourceGroups { get; set; }
}

LinkDestinationGroup :
public class LinkDestinationGroup
{
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

LinkSourceGroup
public class LinkSourceGroup
{
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

LinkDestinationGroupConfiguration :
public class LinkDestinationGroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LinkDestinationGroup>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LinkDestinationGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(c => c.Link)
            .WithMany(c => c.DestinationGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.LinkId);
        builder.HasOne(c => c.Group)
            .WithMany(c => c.DestinationGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.GroupId);
    }
}

LinkSourceGroupDefinition:
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LinkSourceGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(c => c.Link)
            .WithMany(c => c.SourceGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.LinkId);
        builder.HasOne(c => c.Group)
            .WithMany(c => c.SourceGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.GroupId);
    }

Side notes:
Navigation properties are defined with "virtual" keyword for lazy configuration see  => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations
Fluent-Api used for configuring entities, see => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties
Also don't forget to call these configures in your dbcontext's OnModelCreating method like following :
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
      builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(FooDbContext).Assembly);
    }

